# Delete FTP server files after downloading

Tags: powershell

Need to delete files from FTP server using cmdlet command.
Below is the function I tried which downloads the files but struggling with the delete part.

Remove-FTPFile -Client $Client -RemotePath "$($FtpFolder)$($FtpFile)"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is :

```
Remove-FTPFile -Client $Client -RemotePath "$($FtpFolder)/$($FtpFile)"
```